# Complex Integral of $ f(z)=z\cdot \exp(z^2)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Any hint for calculating the integral of  $ f(z)=z\cdot \exp(z^2)$?

1. on  $r=[i, i+2]$,
2. on $t=\{x+ix^2:0\leq x\leq 1\}$

thx!

Comment: Hint: it's not difficult to find a primitive function.

Comment: you can use the parametrization technique to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** try the substitution $w=z^2$.